# How do you use CocoonJS for HTML project

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, cocoonjs

I have a HTML/JS project I created in Eclipse that I want to make cross platform. I came across CocoonJS by Ludei and it seemed like the best option (as they support WebGL)
I followed the instructions on the [Ludei site](http://wiki.ludei.com/cocoonjs%3alauncherapp)

1. I got CocoonJS Launcher on my Android device (Nexus 7)
2. I zipped my HTML/JS project and pushed it to the sdcard
3. There is an index.html file in the root directory
4. The cocoonJS Launcher successfully detected my zip project in the "Your App" section

When I click to launch my project its a black page and in the error log:

> Could not find anything to be executed. If you are using a ZIP file, please, verify that the main HTML or JS file is in the root of the ZIP file (not inside any folder). If you are using a folder path directly, please, check that the main HTML or JS file is stored inside of it.

I have sifted through their website and any forums I could find (not many) but have't figured it out

What am I missing? I have index.html and it doesn't open up.

Answer (score 1):

Did you zip the folder everything was in or did you select all the files and zip them? For example if you have:

```
AppFolder
  |- js/
  |- img/
  |- index.html
```

And you were to zip the "AppFolder" you would then have a zip file which contained a folder of everything else like this:

```
Archive.zip
  |- AppFolder
      |- js/
      |- img/
      |- index.html
```

What you would need to do is highlight the two folders "js" and "img" and the html file and then right click make a zip. This would produce:

```
Archive.zip
  |- js/
  |- img/
  |- index.html
```

And the Cocoon app launcher will be able to find your index.html. This happen to me and was my fix. From the command line I run:

```
zip Archive.zip img/* js/* index.html
```

And this packages everything into an Archive.zip file that I then upload using Cocoon launcher.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that zip command doesn't zip up sub folders, or consider any other packages you might have